# Set value for Django DurationField type in query

Tags: python, django

I want to pass value to DurationField of Django and store it into database.
After check the documentation, I thought we should use timedelta datatype to set Duratioin Field value. Like following code
`record = Record(ID = 1,Duration = DurationField(timedelta(minutes=20)))`

I also tried to using string type and integer type to set Duration's value, but they can't work. So I wander how should we set the value for DurationField type? I'm using the SQLite database.

My model:

```
TimeRecord(models.Model):
    duration = models.DurationField()
```

Instantiate:

```
record = TimeRecord(duration = timedelta(hours=5))
record.save()
```

Comment: Please show the model, the code you have tried to create the model instance, and the error you are seeing.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm Updated. By the way how can I check the detailed error message of server side code. Chrome browser just told me it's 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR). Thanks for your instruction. I think problem happens in inserting data instead of model itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

```python
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models

class TimeRecord(models.Model):
    duration = models.DurationField(default=timedelta(minutes=40))
```

And you can create a record like this :

```python
from datetime import timedelta

# create a new record 
record1 = TimeRecord.objects.create()
record1.duration
# output : datetime.timedelta(0, 2400)
# you can create an another
record2 = TimeRecord.objects.create(duration=timedelta(minutes=20))
record2.duration
# output : datetime.timedelta(0, 1200)
```

Comment: what's is your sqlite version and django version? Is it working if you remove this field and add a CharField for example?